# How to guarantee alignment and stride on Numpy ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy, python-c-extension

I have to interface some Numpy arrays with C code that expect pointers in a given alignment (16 bytes, to be specific). Currently I am simply passing `a.ctypes.data` cast to `double *`, and then copying, on the C side, the data to properly aligned pointers. I want to avoid these copies and C side allocation, so I need two things:

- I have a `ndarray` of shape `(n, n)` that is input to a C function, how can I create it so to ensured that its pointer is aligned and padded to 16 bytes (i.e. both the pointer itself and the size are multiple of 16 bytes)?
- Another `ndarray` of shape `(t, n, n)` holds the output of a C function, how can I create it so that every `a[t]` slice is aligned to 16 bytes (i.e. the stride between `(n, n)` slices is multiple of 16 bytes)?

I saw that an `ndarray` have attributes specifying alignment and stride, but I couldn't find the proper ways to set them. Is it possible? How can I do it?

Comment: Look into `np.require` function. You can require that it is `NPY_ALIGNED`, which would mean that the addresses of every element in your array are alighted at `np.itemsize`, which in your case is 64, a multiple of 16.